# How to compile C code in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want to write a console application in C in VS 2008. What project type do I need to select and what properties I must set in order to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ - Projects - Win32 Project - Console Application. When application is created, rename .cpp files to .c. In the Project Properties, C++, Advanced, select Compile As C code (/TC).

Comment: I like your answer. I thought this is more complicated. If there are no more better answers, I will mark this one as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Win32 Console Project....

then add files....select .cpp, but call it a .c :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console Application